# How to make tsc to infer union type as a single type?

Tags: typescript, interface

```js
interface Music {
    id: number
}
interface AMusic extends Music{
    title: string
}

// please see `selectors` variable below
export type KVPairs<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = K extends keyof T
  ? { key: K; getValue(): T[K] | undefined }
  : never;
type Selector = KVPairs<AMusic>

const selectors: Selector[] = [
    {key: 'id', getValue: () => 1},
    {key: 'title', getValue: () => "hahaha"}
]

const m: Partial<AMusic> = {}

for(const selector of selectors) {
    m[selector.key] = selector.getValue()
}
```

When assigning `selector.getValue()` to `m[selector.key]`, below type error occurs.

> Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type
> 'undefined'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type
> 'undefined'.(2322)

I know `selector.getValue()` and `m[selector.key]` has same type. How can I tell the typescript compiler about this?

Comment: Another case of [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)

Comment: @jcalz Wow. I'll watch the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Note that [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbdq8w) is the current approach I'd suggest here; you probably would prefer the convenient-but-not-safe solution to the safe-but-redundant solution.